# Why does " $Namefile* " give me such a result?

Tags: shell-script, variable

In my code , there is such a part ;

```
Namefile=$1
for n in $Namefile*
do
echo $n
done
```

and just for this part's result is ;

```
$ sh example.sh hw1
hw1_evening_sun.txt
hw1_morning_sun.txt
hw1_out_si_wire.txt
hw1_script.sh
hw1_script2.sh
hw1_script3.sh
hw1_sun1.txt
hw1_sun2.txt
```

which are the files whose name starting with "hw1" , but I don't understand **why $Namefile* takes these names**.As far as I know * calls the the argument which the script receives.

Why does this method work like that ? Could someone explain the logic behind it ?

Comment: Nope, `*` expands, You must be giving `hw1` as it's first parameter; Otherwise the `pwd` at that moment would be containg files all of which starting with `hw1`.

Comment: Yes , you are right .I forgot to add the input.

Comment: That behavior is normal since you are saying hw1* if you need the parameters you have to use $* for debugging purposes you can use the set -x

Comment: İf it won't be a problem , could you briefly explain "set -x" part ?

Comment: set -x will expand the results of every line in your she'll script, sorry for being so late I'm on the road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why $Namefile* takes these names.As far as I know * calls the the argument which the script receives.

$Namefile expands to the value that you passed in (probably "hw").  This means that $Namefile* after variable expansion becomes "hw*".

When this string is used in a location where it is interpreted as a filename, the * is special.  See "pathname expansion" in the man page.

> ... bash  scans
>          each  word  for the characters *, ?, and [.  If one of these characters
>          appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced  with  an
>          alphabetically  sorted  list of file names matching the pattern.

Comment: in the man page ?

Comment: Feel free to use documentation in any form.  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion

Answer (score 1):

Here you are doing a substitution in you for loop. So star will match every character after `$Namefile` string (which I guess it is "hw1"). If you want to match all the arguments provided to the script use the internal variable `$*`.
In your script you are saving `$1` (positional parameter number 1) which is wh1 to the variable Namefile. So using * after `$Namefile` has a different meaning than `$*`. For more info see here [Internal Variables](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) (Positional Parameters section)

Comment: I've already said what you say in the question.The problem is why it does that ? In definition $* must take the receiving statements not the file names.

Comment: Notice that `$*` is not the same as `$Namefile*`!

Comment: But still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I think it should be clear now. Which part of the answer is not clear?

Comment: So , how does hw1* call the file names which start with hw1 just by itself ?

Comment: `$Namefile*` expands to the all file names in the current directory starting with Namefile (hw1). And the for loops over those files and echos them.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because of `-l` option of `ls`. In this case, because `$Namefile*` would expand to `hw1_evening_sun.txt ..snip.. hw1_sun2.txt`:

```
ls -l $Namefile*
```

is effectively equals to

```
ls -l hw1_evening_sun.txt ..snip.. hw1_sun2.txt
```

For more information, you can run `man ls`. Here I quote:

```
...  
   -l     use a long listing format  
...
```

Welcome to *nix.

Comment: But as I said in question , I am asking why $Namefile* take these values without  ls -l $Namefile.

Comment: @Leth because the shell expands wildcards, not ls.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your do loop is so. For the output to be as expected for `-l` you would need to execute your *that part* of script inside the backticks as below.

---

tmp.sh

```
Namefile=$1
for n in $Namefile*
do
echo $n
done
```

---

Run that particular part as,

```
ls -l `./tmp.sh "d"`

-bash-3.2$ ls -l `./again d`
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Jun  3 05:16 dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Jun  3 05:16 dis
```